# SQLite DB Query

Tags: android, sqlite

I am building an `SQLite` DB. One of the tables consists of 2 columns - term and definition.

My question is : **How can I query the DB, in order the pair term-definition to be returned in order to be able to insert the data in the activity** after that (the term and data are in `ExpandableListView`, the term is the Key, the data - the value).

Here is the code of the data source so far:

```
public class TermDataSource extends DAO {

//constants
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "terms";
public static final String TERM = "term";
public static final String DEFINITION = "definition";

//columns in the table
public static final int FIELD_ID_ID = 0;
public static final int FIELD_ID_TERM = 1;
public static final int FIELD_ID_DEFINITION = 2;

public TermDataSource (Context context){
    super(context);
}

private String [] selectFields = {_ID, TERM, DEFINITION};

public Cursor getTermsData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, selectFields, null, null, null, null, null);

    return cursor;
}
public List<Term> getTerms(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, selectFields, null, null, null, null, null);
    List<Term> terms = new ArrayList<Term>();

    if(cursor!=null){

        Term term = null;
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            term = getTermFromCursor(cursor);
            terms.add(term);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    db.close();
    return terms;
}

private Term getTermFromCursor (Cursor cursor){
    Term term = new Term();
    term.setTermId(cursor.getInt(FIELD_ID_ID));
    term.setTerm(cursor.getString(FIELD_ID_TERM));
    term.setDefinition(cursor.getString(FIELD_ID_DEFINITION));

    return term;
}
}
```

Comment: Means do you want to get data using _term and definition_ for specific value ?

Comment: I want to fill them in with data from a CSV file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a folder `res>raw` and put `youfile.csv` in that folder.

Use this method to insert data in Your Database from `CSV` file.

```
public void insertCSVData(Activity activity, InputStream is, String tableName) {

    String colunmNames = null, str1 = null;
    open();

    try {

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = "";

        String str2 = ");";

        db.beginTransaction();

        int i = 0;
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            i++;
            if (i == 1) {
                colunmNames = line;
                str1 = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + colunmNames + ") values (";
            } else {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str1);
                String[] str = line.split(",");

                for (int h = 0; h < str.length; h++) {

                    if (h == str.length - 1) {
                        sb.append("'" + str[h] + "'");
                    } else {
                        sb.append("'" + str[h] + "',");
                    }
                }

                sb.append(str2);
                db.execSQL(sb.toString());
            }
        }

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        close();

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    close();
}
```

Call this method by the below code :

```
insertCSVData(Activity.this, getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourfile),"Your Table Name");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll come back with a feedback after testing :)

Comment: My pleasure.. Happy coding..!!